# I need to map a complex type relationship with many tables

Tags: .net, angular, entity-framework, api, orm

Ok, i have this Class 'Opciones', I'm sorry it's in spanish. The main thing to understand is that i have this class 'Opciones' which has multiple instances of itself in 'Registro' and i can't find a way to map this right with Entity framework, i'm using migrations since i gotta stick to the structure of the DB. I've got it to retrieve data from the DB but when it gets to the field which is the complex type it just brings null, and 0 inside the values of the properties.

I've tried to configure the mapping inside the OnModelCreating method, nothing has worked, it ends up asking for a "propertyNameId" like tipoClienteId column, and what i'd like it to do is to go on and search in opciones table and retrieve the information according to the id found in the property, but to my app its a property of a class that is an object it self. It's my first time dealing with entity framework and mapping so any clarification on the matter it's well received.

```
public class Registro
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string usuarioRed { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaLlamada { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaDevolucion { get; set; }
        public Opciones tipoCliente { get; set; }
        public Opciones motivoDevolucion { get; set; }
}

public class Opciones
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public Boolean activo { get; set; }
        public int idDependencia { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: First, are you trying to map this in Angular?  If so, are you getting the data in angular?  If so, please show your angular code.

Comment: in the db is registro to opciones one to many? because that relationsship will work in ef.  It will store the fk to opciones in registro.

Comment: Yes, im trying to consume the data in an angular project but i have back and front end in different projects, the backend is a .net api, im testing with postman.

Comment: I find quite difficult to explain the relationship between this entities in DB, let's say Registro or any other entity just 'consumes' the data from opciones, and what you find inside registro is an id that points to a record in opciones, it should be a simple one to one relationship but opciones as an entity is instantiated many times inside other entities.

Answer (score 0):

For Entity Framework, to create a relationship between Entities you have to add the ID and the Object

```
public class Registro
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string usuarioRed { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaLlamada { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaDevolucion { get; set; }

        public int tipoClienteId { get; set; }
        public Opciones tipoCliente { get; set; }

        public int motivoDevolucionId { get; set; }
        public Opciones motivoDevolucion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, in DB, there is no column for tipoClienteId, there's a column that does contains the Id which is an int, but don't know how that's gonna map to my entity in ef. If im confused, please enlighten me.